# Reactive: Caching service response for few hours

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

So my application would call below expensive HTTP service multiple times (simultaneously by multiple threads with same as well as different Ids for every client request to my application).

```
Mono<Foo> response = myService.fetch(id);
```

I would like to cache the response (in-memory) for few hours, and then only on next client request make only one call to refresh the cache.

**Approach 1:**

```
Mono<Foo> cachedResponse = Mono.empty();

public Mono<Foo> get(String id){
   return cachedResponse.switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(()-> 
    {
       cachedResponse = myService.fetch(id).cache(Duration.ofHours(4));
       return cachedResponse;
    }));    
}
```

is following approach OK? Specifically since multiple threads could call get method with same id. Also, when the cache is invalidated after 4 hours, would it make cachedResponse Mono empty for switchIfEmpty to work correctly?

**Approach 2:**
I could use some caching solution to store cache for few hours. e.g.

```
Foo getFromCacheSolution(String id);
```

and then,

```
public Mono<Foo> get(String id){
   Foo cachedFoo = getFromCacheSolution(id);
   if(cachedFoo != null){
      return Mono.just(cachedFoo);
   }
   else{
      return myService.fetch(id).doOnNext(value->storeToCacheSolution(id, value)); //line 7
   }
}
```

The problem with this solution is that line 7 would be called multiple times resulting in multiple calls to expensive fetch service (for example if 3 threads enter into get method with id 123 and cachedFoo is null). Making method synchronized may not help as line 7 would complete instantaneously.

One work-around would be to store Mono in the cache solution instead of Foo (not sure if that's a good idea or not):

```
Mono<Foo> getFromCacheSolution(String id); //returns cached or empty Mono
```

and then,

```
public Mono<Foo> get(String id){
   return getFromCacheSolution(id).switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(()-> 
    {
       cachedResponse = myService.fetch(id).doOnNext(value->storeToCacheSolution(id, value));
       return cachedResponse;
    }));
}
```

Any recommendations or better alternatives?

Comment: I like the second solution more but maybe [caching helper](https://projectreactor.io/docs/extra/snapshot/api/reactor/cache/CacheMono.html) from reactor-extra project could help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question consists of two parts: about caching and about exclusive locking for calls with same parameters.

1. Caching.

   Your second approach is good for in-memory cache. Alternatively you could use `CacheMono` from the [reactor-extra](https://projectreactor.io/docs/extra/snapshot/api/reactor/cache/CacheMono.html)

   ```java
   Mono<Foo> myFoo =
           CacheMono.lookup(key -> Mono.justOrEmpty(myCache.getIfPresent(key))
                   .map(Signal::next), id)
                   .onCacheMissResume(() -> myService.fetch(id))
                   .andWriteWith((key, signal) -> Mono.fromRunnable(() ->
                           Optional.ofNullable(signal.get())
                                   .ifPresent(value -> myCache.put(key, value))));
   ```
2. Exclusive locking for calls with same parameters.

   Usually we should avoid any locking in the reactive world. But if you really need it, your lock should be nonblocking. I don't know any library, but you could find some ideas and links with examples in [this question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998809/nonblocking-reentrantlock-with-reactor)