# Cache not working properly using Reactor and Caffeine

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, caffeine

I need to check some endpoints in different intervals, so I set up the Caffeine's cache builder .

`this.localeWeatherCache = newBuilder().build();`

`this.currentWeatherCache=newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(Duration.ofHours(3)).build();`

`this.weatherForecastsCache = newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(Duration.ofHours(12)).build();`

In my Service I call those 3 endpoints, in the end I return my object with all details usin Mono.zip().

During my tests, I noticed that **climaTempoRepository.findLocaleByCityNameAndState is executed twice** and after the **currentWeather** cache expires it makes another call to **locale** endpoint, the same happens with weatherForecast, it calls again the **locale**.

Why it fails? Shouldn't it use cache? Or the way I did is wrong?

Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated! :)

```
public Mono<Weather> weatherForecastByLocation(Location location) {

    Mono<ClimaTempoLocale> locale =
            CacheMono.lookup(key ->
                    Mono.justOrEmpty(localeWeatherCache.getIfPresent(key))
                            .map(Signal::next), location)
                    .onCacheMissResume(() -> climaTempoRepository.findLocaleByCityNameAndState(location.city(), location.state()))
                    .andWriteWith((key, signal) -> Mono.fromRunnable(() ->
                            Optional.ofNullable(signal.get())
                                    .ifPresent(value -> localeWeatherCache.put(key, value))));

    Mono<CurrentWeather> currentWeather =
            CacheMono.lookup(key ->
                    Mono.justOrEmpty(currentWeatherCache.getIfPresent(key))
                            .map(Signal::next), location)
                    .onCacheMissResume(() -> locale.flatMap(climaTempoRepository::findCurrentWeatherByLocale)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()))
                    .andWriteWith((key, signal) -> Mono.fromRunnable(() ->
                            Optional.ofNullable(signal.get())
                                    .ifPresent(value -> currentWeatherCache.put(key, value))));

    Mono<WeatherForecasts> weatherForecasts =
            CacheMono.lookup(key ->
                    Mono.justOrEmpty(weatherForecastsCache.getIfPresent(key))
                            .map(Signal::next), location)
                    .onCacheMissResume(() -> locale.flatMap(climaTempoRepository::findDailyForecastByLocale)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()))
                    .andWriteWith((key, signal) -> Mono.fromRunnable(() ->
                            Optional.ofNullable(signal.get())
                                    .ifPresent(value -> weatherForecastsCache.put(key, value))));

    return Mono.zip(currentWeather,
            weatherForecasts,
            (current, forecasts) ->
                    Weather.buildWith(builder -> {
                        builder.location = location;
                        builder.currentWeather = current;
                        builder.weatherForecasts = forecasts;
                    }));

}
```

Comment: Perhaps because you are not computing through the cache, so multiple calls could happen in parallel? The cache is being queried, the results fetched outside of it, and inserted manually. If two callers see it is absent then both would do the work, right?

Comment: Thanks @BenManes for your help. Yes, multiple calls are happen. Is that possible to you give me some suggestion how to resolve that, how can I compute through the cache?

Comment: Could you use `AsyncCache` and `Mono#fromFuture` to translate to your api? e.g. `var currentWeather  = Mono.fromFuture(cache.get(key, climaTempoRepository::findCurrentWeatherByLocale));`

Answer (score 3):

A `AsyncLoadingCache` can compute the value from the key and returns a `CompletableFuture` of the result. This can be translated into a `Mono` it's `fromFuture` method. This will ensure only a single execution is in-flight for a given key, while not blocking due to storing the futures within the cache.

```
AsyncLoadingCache<Location, ClimaTempoLocale> localeWeatherCache = 
    Caffeine.newBuilder().buildAsync(location -> 
        climaTempoRepository.findLocaleByCityNameAndState(location.city(), location.state()));

AsyncLoadingCache<ClimaTempoLocale, CurrentWeather> currentWeatherCache =
    Caffeine.newBuilder().buildAsync(climaTempoRepository::findCurrentWeatherByLocale);

AsyncLoadingCache<ClimaTempoLocale, WeatherForecasts> weatherForecastsCache =
    Caffeine.newBuilder().buildAsync(climaTempoRepository::findDailyForecastByLocale);

public Mono<Weather> weatherForecastByLocation(Location location) {
  var locale = Mono.fromFuture(localeWeatherCache.get(location));
  var currentWeather = Mono.fromFuture(locale.map(localeWeatherCache::get));
  var weatherForecasts = Mono.fromFuture(locale.map(weatherForecastsCache::get));

  return Mono.zip(currentWeather, weatherForecasts, (current, forecasts) ->
      Weather.buildWith(builder -> {
          builder.location = location;
          builder.currentWeather = current;
          builder.weatherForecasts = forecasts;
      }));
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how the key is defined in the  below example?  ``CacheMono.lookup(
                    key -> Mono.justOrEmpty(weatherForecastsCache.getIfPresent(key))
                            .map(Signal::next)``

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know Reactor and `CacheMono` might not be worth using due to [stampede concerns](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons/issues/237).

Comment: so are there any alternatives?

Comment: PS: Wow, I just found out that, u r the author of Caffeine :D

Comment: @namila007 Instead of `CacheMono`, you can convert between `CompletableFuture` and `Mono` using `Mono.fromFuture(future)` and `mono.toFuture()`. This should protect against stampedes and be more straightforward, with a little noise due to the converters.

Answer (score 2):

As exemplified here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52803247/11209784 the `ClimaTempoLocale` could be computed as follows:

```java
Cache<Location, ClimaTempoLocale> weatherLocaleCache = Caffeine.newBuilder().build();

private Mono<ClimaTempoLocale> findLocale(Location location) {
    Mono<ClimaTempoLocale> locale;
    ClimaTempoLocale cachedLocale = weatherLocaleCache.getIfPresent(location);
    if (cachedLocale != null) {
        locale = Mono.just(cachedLocale);
    } else {
        locale = climaTempoRepository.findLocaleByCityNameAndState(location.city(), location.state())
                .doOnNext(climaTempoLocale -> weatherLocaleCache.put(location, climaTempoLocale));
    }

    return locale;
}
```

One side effect is that there can be consecutive writes to the same key when concurrent calls result in cache miss.

By doing this, the calls that depend on the `ClimaTempoLocale` could continue the same way:

```java
Cache<Location, CurrentWeather> currentWeatherCache = Caffeine.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(Duration.ofHours(3)).build();

Cache<Location, WeatherForecasts> weatherForecastsCache = Caffeine.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(Duration.ofHours(12)).build();

public Mono<Weather> weatherForecastByLocation(Location location) {
    Mono<ClimaTempoLocale> locale = findLocale(location);

    Mono<CurrentWeather> currentWeather =
            CacheMono.lookup(
                    key -> Mono.justOrEmpty(currentWeatherCache.getIfPresent(key))
                            .map(Signal::next),
                    location)
                    .onCacheMissResume(
                            () -> locale.flatMap(climaTempoRepository::findCurrentWeatherByLocale)
                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()))
                    .andWriteWith(
                            (key, signal) -> Mono.fromRunnable(
                                    () -> Optional.ofNullable(signal.get())
                                            .ifPresent(value -> currentWeatherCache.put(key, value))));

    Mono<WeatherForecasts> weatherForecasts =
            CacheMono.lookup(
                    key -> Mono.justOrEmpty(weatherForecastsCache.getIfPresent(key))
                            .map(Signal::next),
                    location)
                    .onCacheMissResume(
                            () -> locale.flatMap(climaTempoRepository::findDailyForecastByLocale)
                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()))
                    .andWriteWith(
                            (key, signal) -> Mono.fromRunnable(
                                    () -> Optional.ofNullable(signal.get())
                                            .ifPresent(value -> weatherForecastsCache.put(key, value))));

    return Mono.zip(currentWeather,
            weatherForecasts,
            (current, forecasts) ->
                    Weather.buildWith(builder -> {
                        builder.location = location;
                        builder.currentWeather = current;
                        builder.weatherForecasts = forecasts;
                    }));
}
```